# ASP MVC 5 Empty Model List after Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I've been around this for a couple of time and I would love if possible for a couple of "fresh" pair of eyes to look at this.

In my app I have a form where I use a model with some primitive types and two lists. Also I'm using a Kendo grid.

My problem is that when the user does Submit, the model arrives ok but one of the two lists returns with 0 elements...! (never null)

The list that arrives ok is the one I'm creating in the Kendo Grid.

The list that returns empty is List ProductItemlist, that is generated in the partial view (also tried not using the partial view).

The thing is, on the controller if I do:

string test = Request.Form["ProductItemlist[0].ProductItemId"],

I get the values I want, so the problem I think must be in the mapping.

Nevertheless I'm failing in discovering it....

What's happenning...? Thanks in advance for any help!

My Model:

```
public class PurchaseRegistrationProductEditVM
    {
public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public int EnterpriseId { get; set; }

    public int HeadquarterId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    public int? RUC { get; set; }

    public string RUCName { get; set; }

    public string RUCAddress { get; set; }

    public List<PurchaseRegistrationProductItemEditVM> ProductItemlist { get; set; }

    public List<ClientProductPurchaseRegistryComissionEditVM> ComissionList { get; set; }

}
```

Model PurchaseRegistrationProductItemEditVM:

```
public class PurchaseRegistrationProductItemEditVM{

 public int ProductItemId { get; set; }

    public string ProductItemName { get; set; }

    public int ProductItemTypeId { get; set; }

    public string ProductItemTypeName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? StartCourseDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EndCourseDate { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public int ExpiryDays { get; set; }

    public string Size { get; set; }

    public int DiscountTypeId { get; set; }

    public string DiscountTypeName { get; set; }

    public decimal? Discount { get; set; }

    public int? MonthlyPaymentDueDay { get; set; }

    public decimal? MonthlyPaymentDuePenalty { get; set; }

    public DateTime MatriculationStartDate { get; set; }

    public string MatriculationObservation { get; set; }

}
```

Model: ClientProductPurchaseRegistryComissionEditVM

```
public class ClientProductPurchaseRegistryComissionEditVM
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ClientProductPurchaseRegistryId { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string Observations { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@model PurchaseRegistrationProductEditVM

@{
Layout = "~/Areas/Backoffice/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


        @using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessPurchases", "Client"))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClientId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EndDate)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EnterpriseId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HeadquarterId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StartDate)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StatusId)


                                @Html.Partial("_PartialViewProductItem")

                                <div class="form_sep">
                                        @Html.Label(Resources.Client_Pending_Payment_Label_Comission)
                                    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                                        .Name("EmployeeComissionComboBox")
                                        .Placeholder(Resources.Employee_ComboBox)
                                        .DataTextField("Text")
                                        .DataValueField("Value")
                                        .Filter(FilterType.Contains)

                                        .DataSource(source =>
                                        {
                                            source.Read(read =>
                                            {
                                                read.Action("GetEmployeesComboBox", "Client", new { EnterpriseId = @Model.EnterpriseId });
                                            })
                                            .ServerFiltering(true);

                                        })
                                    )
                                </div>
                                <div class="form_sep">
                                    @Html.Label(Resources.Client_Purchase_Registry_Comission_Field_Observations)
                                    @Html.TextBox("PurchaseComissionObservations", "", new { maxlength = 50, size = 10, @class = "form-control" })


                                </div>
                                <div class="form_sep">

                                    @(Html.Kendo().Button()
                                    .Name("EmployeeComissionAddButton")
                                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button", @class = "k-primary" })
                                    .Content(Resources.Client_SelectedPayments_Button_Add_Employee_Comission)
                                    .Events(ev => ev.Click("onClickAddEmployeeComission"))
                                    )
                                </div>

                                <div class="form_sep">
                                    @Html.Label(Resources.Client_Purchase_Registry_Grid_Added_Employees)
                                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ClientProductPurchaseRegistryComissionEditVM>()
                                        .Name("PurchaseCommissionGrid")
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:150px;" })
                                        .Columns(columns =>
                                        {
                                            columns.Bound(o => o.EmployeeName).Filterable(f => f.Cell(c => c.ShowOperators(false))).ClientTemplate("#= EmployeeName #<input type='hidden' name='ComissionList[#= indexPurchaseComissionGrid(data)#].EmployeeName' value='#= EmployeeName #' />");
                                            columns.Bound(o => o.EmployeeId).Hidden().Filterable(f => f.Cell(c => c.ShowOperators(false))).ClientTemplate("#= EmployeeId #<input type='hidden' name='ComissionList[#= indexPurchaseComissionGrid(data)#].EmployeeId' value='#= EmployeeId #' />");
                                            columns.Bound(o => o.Observations).Filterable(f => f.Cell(c => c.ShowOperators(false))).ClientTemplate("#= Observations #<input type='hidden' name='ComissionList[#= indexPurchaseComissionGrid(data)#].Observations' value='#= Observations #' />");
                                            columns.Command(command =>
                                            {
                                                command.Custom("Remove").Text(Resources.Site_Link_Remove).Click("onDeleteEmployeeComission");
                                            });
                                        })
                                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .PageSize(5)
                                        )
                                        .Pageable()
                                        .Sortable()
                                        .Scrollable())
                                </div>

                                <div class="form_sep">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RUC)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RUC, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RUC)
                                </div>

                                <div class="form_sep">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RUCName)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RUCName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RUCName)
                                </div>

                                <div class="form_sep">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RUCAddress)
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RUCAddress, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RUCAddress)

                        <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="@Resources.FO_Client_Link_Buy_Product" class="btn btn-default" />
                        @Html.ActionLink(Resources.Site_Link_Back, "PurchaseProduct/" + @Model.ClientId, "Client", new { Area = "Frontoffice" }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })

        }
```

Partial View:

```
@model PurchaseRegistrationProductEditVM

 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductItemlist.Count; i++)
{
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].Amount)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].Discount)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].DiscountTypeId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].DiscountTypeName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].EndCourseDate)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].ExpiryDays)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].MonthlyPaymentDueDay)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].MonthlyPaymentDuePenalty)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].ProductItemId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].ProductItemName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].ProductItemTypeId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].ProductItemTypeName)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].Size)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].StartCourseDate)

if (Model.ProductItemlist[i].ProductItemTypeId == 1)
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    if (date < Model.ProductItemlist[i].StartCourseDate.Value)
    {
        date = Model.ProductItemlist[i].StartCourseDate.Value;
    }

    //Case Course

    <div class="form_sep">
        <b>@Resources.Site_Link_Course&nbsp;@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].ProductItemName)</b>
    </div>
    <div class="form_sep">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].MatriculationStartDate)
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].MatriculationStartDate)
                                                .Animation(true)
                                                .Culture("pt-PT")
                                                .Format("dd-MM-yyyy")
                                                .Value(date)
                                                .Min(Model.ProductItemlist[i].StartCourseDate.Value)
                                                .Max(Model.ProductItemlist[i].EndCourseDate.Value)
        )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].MatriculationStartDate)
    </div>

    //Observations
    <div class="form_sep">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].MatriculationObservation)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].MatriculationObservation, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductItemlist[i].MatriculationObservation)
    </div>
}
```

}

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessPurchases(PurchaseRegistrationProductEditVM model)
    {
        Log.Instance.Info(string.Format(LogConst.CONTROLLER, "Client", "ProcessPayments", "Get"));

        string test = Request.Form["ProductItemlist[0].ProductItemId"];

                return RedirectToAction("Details/" + model.ClientId, "Client");

}
```

Comment: The code you have shown looks as though it should bind to the collection. Often a collection that is not null but has items means you posting back non zero-based indexers (i.e. have deleted the first item in the collection) but if your getting the value using `Request.Form["ProductItemlist[0].ProductItemId"]` then that's not the issue. Other common causes are that the properties have no setters or are not public. Again your code looks OK.

Comment: The real question here is why on earth you have all those hidden fields. You should use a view model which contains only those properties necessary in the view. Rendering a whole lot of extra html and then posting it back unchanged is just going to degrade your application. A hidden input that identifies the ID of the item in the collection is all that should be rendered.

Comment: I can do a query and replace all the hidden fields. After a good night sleep I was able to solve this issue! :) In the end the problem was this line: @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist). Since I was already storing a list of the same type the form mapper used the first he got. And since you can't save entire lists in hidden fields... it returned a list with 0 elements! Thank you a lot for the help Stephen!

Answer (score 1):

After a good night sleep I was able to solve this issue! :)

In the end the problem was this line:

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductItemlist)

Since I was already storing a list of the same type the form mapper used the first he got. And since you can't save entire lists in hidden fields... it returned a list initialized with 0 elements!

After deleting the line everything started working like a charm!